# Node.JS MySQL Connection Timing Out

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, timeout, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to have my Alexa skill say the result of my database query, as shown below. However, I'm receiving a timeout error and Alexa simply says, "There as a problem with the requested skill's response."

This code is running in AWS Lambda and uses the mySQL module.

```
   'LaunchRequest': function () {
console.log('starting Launch');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'bfdfdfm',
  user     : 'test',
  password : 'test',
  database : 'test',
  port     : '1433'
});

console.log('step2');

connection.connect();
console.log('step3');

connection.query('SELECT `book` FROM `dbo.tblBibleBooks` WHERE `id` = "4"', function (error, results, fields) {
  console.log('step4');
  if (error) console.log('did not work');
  console.log('The solution is: ', results);
  this.emit(':tell', results);
});

connection.end();
```

Here's the console log with error messages. Remarkably, none of my console log values are recorded!

```
2018-02-06T17:05:01.828Z    de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a    initializing
START RequestId: de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a Version: $LATEST
2018-02-06T17:05:02.184Z    de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a    starting Launch
2018-02-06T17:05:03.543Z    de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a    step2
2018-02-06T17:05:03.761Z    de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a    step3
END RequestId: de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a
REPORT RequestId: de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a  Duration: 10000.98 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 45 MB  
2018-02-06T17:05:12.088Z de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a Task timed out after 10.00 seconds

2018-02-06T17:05:12.254Z    de66d608-0b5f-11e8-a70a-6f7ecc1bb68a    initializing
START RequestId: e4b89244-0b5f-11e8-9e15-6d418568d36a Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: e4b89244-0b5f-11e8-9e15-6d418568d36a
REPORT RequestId: e4b89244-0b5f-11e8-9e15-6d418568d36a  Duration: 176.56 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 33 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would be taking 7sec to respond, but you need to make sure your Lambda timeout under "Basic Settings" is greater than the time your query takes.  I would set it to 10 seconds and test again.

[image]

EDITED:
If you aren't seeing any of your console.log messages, it isn't executing the code.  Try the following code to see if you can get any response from MySQL and verify the response in your logs.  This code assumes that you have the necessary libraries for MySQL already packaged and uploaded to your Lambda function.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = {
  host     : '.....amazonaws.com',
  user     : 'dafsdf',
  password : 'jasdf',
  database : 'asdf',
  port     : '1433'
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  
  var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
  
    const sql = 'SELECT `book` FROM `dbo.tblBibleBooks` WHERE `id` = "4"'
    
    connection.connect();

    connection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (!err)
        {
          console.log('The solution is: ', results);
           this.emit(':tell', results);
        }
      else
        {
          console.log('Error while performing Query.');
          this.emit('error', err);
        }
    });
    
    connection.end();
  
};
```

Comment: Tried that, no success. I'm timing out even at 12 seconds. Interestingly, I checked my database immediately after running the function and it showed one active connection. So apparently my connection to the database is running successfully, but I'm still timing out for some reason.

Comment: Can you insert       console.log('The solution is: ', results);    to make sure the Lambda function is getting something back from MySQL?

Comment: This didn't work. In fact, none of my console log values are showing up. See my updated post with the updated code and error messages.

Comment: I tried the new code. Still nothing in the console logs. Interestingly, when I test the function via the Alexa Simulator, the JSON output looks like this (below). The speech output comes from my "Unhandled" function.

`{
 "body": {
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
   "outputSpeech": {
    "type": "SSML",
    "ssml": "<speak> Goodbye. </speak>"
   },
   "shouldEndSession": true
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
 }`

Comment: Okay, so I've made some tweaks to the code (see above edits) and now my console logs are showing up. But the code breaks after step three. For some reason, the connection.query task is throwing the error. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I've tried `console.log('State:' + connection.state); ` at various points in your code and it always returns "Disconnected" as the state of the MySQL connection.  You will likely need to review the logs on the MySQL side and verify any security settings, like if you are connected through VPC.